# Deduplication while loading to BigQuery

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I have new records to insert to BQ. How do I add only those that are not there? Deduplication while loading.

for example I have in BQ

```
id | text
-----
1 one
2 two
3 three
```

I want to add

```
3 three 
4 four
```

and I want to end up with

```
1 one
2 two
3 three
4 four
```

(so to deduplicate `3 three` record).

I want to use python script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always use set-based operations. Just use the MERGE Statement. First put them all into a dataset (I call it source) and merge them into the target dataset (called target).

```
MERGE dataset.target T
USING dataset.source S
ON T.id = S.id
WHEN NOT MATCHED
INSERT(id, text)
  VALUES(id, text)
```

Of course you can do more powerful things, you get the idea. Disclaimer: This is not tested.